# Computed Order by in entity framwork

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-5

I have a weblog that created by asp.net mvc and entity frame work code first
I want to show top N (for example top 10) posts by condition in two way inside of page in two place

1- By this rule

**Point - (DateTime.Now - CreationDate)**

Point and CreationDate are entities of table post

(I want top N newes by most point Posts)

2-Top N newes post by most Comment

**How can Make these two query by Linq to Entity?**

```
 public class Post
 {

     public int Id { get; set; }

     public string Subject { get; set; }

     public string Description { get; set; }

     public DateTime CreationDate { get; set; }

     public int Point { get; set; }

     public virtual IList<Comment> Comments { get; set; }


}




  public class Comment
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Description { get; set; }

        public Virtual Post Post { get; set;}
    }
```

**Edit**
I want order of viewing Post is a function of Point and CreationDate
a query like this:

```
var latestPosts = dbContext.Posts
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Point - (DateTime.Now - p.CreationDate).TotalDays)
    .Take(postCount)ToList();
```

But it raise error

Comment: It sounds like you need `OrderBy()`, but your question is a bit unclear.

Comment: What you have so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here are 2 queries to your question:

> Get the latest X Posts based on CreationDate

```
var latestPosts = dbContext.Posts
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.CreationDate)
    .Take(postCount);
```

---

> Get X posts with the most comments

```
var mostCommentedPosts = dbContext.Posts
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Comments.Count)
    .Take(postCount);
```

Please comment if I got my interpretations wrong.

Comment: I want place more complex condition in OrderBy please see Edit part of my question